# SAP GUI Scripting "Invalid use of property" Error in VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Hello I am using SAP GUI Scripting tool which uses Excel VBA functionality to complete the task. I am getting `Invalid use of property` at `Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine` line of code:

```
If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Not sure, but if `Application` is not an object, you can't use the `Set` keywaord for assignment.

Comment: How is Application declared? If this is running in Excel VBA then VBA is going to interpret Application, with no declaration, as the Excel application. That would certainly not be correct. Beyond that, is the sytax on the right side of the equation correct? GetScriptingEngine sounds like a method, what does it return? Does it return, or is it expecting a ByRef parameter? You're also missing relevant tags that would make this visible to people who know something about the SAP Scripting tool...

Comment: Thanks . The issue was resolved by renaming the variable Application as Sapplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to rename the variable `Application` to another name.

`Application` is here used like a variable, but it is also a pre-defined read-only object in Excel.

Comment: Yes the issue was resolved by renaming the Application variable in the code as Sapplication.